# How to concatenate base url with another variable in code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to concatenate the base url with another variable which should be public in the class. How can I do this?

Here is my code :

```
class site extends CI_Controller 
{
  public $site_favicon = base_url().'img/favicon.ico';
 // I tried even       public $site_favicon = base_url();.'img/favicon.ico';
}
```

Where i will call the variable `$t` publicly any where from the site.

How can i do this ?

This is how I will call:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo $this->site_favicon; ?>">
```

I am getting:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/ci/application/controllers/site.php on line 23
```

What mistake am I doing in concatenation and how can i fix this?

Comment: What value are you getting when you echo `$site_favicon` ?

Comment: Obviously missing a semi colon probably at the end of line 22

Comment: @Jenz: I am just getting the above error

Comment: @ElefantPhace though i try to concatinate as public $site_favicon = base_url();.'img/favicon.ico'; i am getting the same error

Comment: Downvoter : May i know the reason for downvote ?

Comment: Which is your line 23? And what is the value of `base_url()`

Comment: @Jenz :  public $site_favicon = base_url().'img/favicon.ico'; is my line no 23

Comment: @Jenz: I am getting the correct value if i echo base_url(); individually. The output is http://localhost/ci/ which i set in the conf file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this

```
class site extends CI_Controller 
{
     public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('url'));
        $url=$this->config->base_url();
        $this->site_favicon=$url.'img/favicon.ico';
    }
}
```

Now you can access `site_favicon` in functions with `echo $this->site_favicon;`

`<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo $this->site_favicon ?>">`

Note : If you want variables set in the constructor accessible, then you have to set them as a class property ie., like `$this->variablename` and access them in the same way with `$this->variablename` in your functions.

Comment: can `$this->site_favicon` variable access on view?

Comment: I am not getting error but i am getting empty value while i use this in my view **<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php $this->site_favicon ?>">**

Comment: @Girish.Yes. In the same manner it will be available in view also

Comment: @CiiLearner..You have to echo it. `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo $this->site_favicon ?>">`

Comment: @Jenz: Thanks I am getting it correct. ( If you find my question is valid. Kindly upvote it too)

Comment: @CiiLearner..Glad to help you

Comment: how could it possible.. until you have not passed variables value in load view function `$this->load->view("viewName", array("favicon" => $favicon));`

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign `function` inside class varable, `base_url` is helper function, that is initialized in system autoload 
So you can use directly in **views**
Try this way

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo base_url("img/favicon.ico"); ?>">
```

OR

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo base_url()."img/favicon.ico"; ?>">
```

UPDATE: You should assign favicon value in view variable, the view variables are defined in controller -> action method

In controller

```
$favicon = base_url().'img/favicon.ico';
$this->load->view("viewName", array("favicon" => $favicon));
```

In view you can access variable

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php $favicon; ?>">
```

**NOTE**: you can't access controller class variable value directly in view

Comment: Thanks i am getting. But i don't want to use the base_url() in the view. I just want to assign the value for $site_favicon; as there are several pages in my website. (But i am able to assign other variables just inside the calss)

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$favicon' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/ci/application/controllers/site.php on line 23 Same error. Let me try in few min and convey you ji